# How to store latitude and longitude coordinates dynamically based on current mapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following code that executes if the user clicks either the zoom out or zoom in button:

```
 - (void)zoomHandler:(CGFloat)currentZoom
 {
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition **cameraWithLatitude:40.790218 longitude:-73.959722** zoom:currentZoom];
self.mapView.camera = camera;
 }
```

However, if the user goes away from the above default coordinates, and clicks either button, he/she will be taken back to the above default coordinates. I want the user to be able to zoom in/out on the current mapView that is displayed - and not be taken back automatically to the coordinates that is declared in the method above.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Create two variable to store your current coordinate location:

```
CLLocationDegrees latitude,longitude;

       -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
        {
        CGPoint point = self.mapView.center;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coor = [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point];
        longitude = coor.longitude;
        latitude = coor.latitude;
        }
```

You may use code in below method to perform zooming:

```
        -(void)zoomInAction {
        CGFloat currentZoom = self.mapView.camera.zoom;
        currentZoom = currentZoom + 1.0;

        if(currentZoom < self.mapView.maxZoom) {
          GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                                  longitude:longitude
                                                                       zoom:currentZoom];
          self.mapView.camera = camera;
          [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
          }
        }

        -(void)zoomOutAction {
        CGFloat currentZoom = self.mapView.camera.zoom;
        currentZoom = currentZoom - 1.0;
        if(currentZoom > self.mapView.minZoom) {
         GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                                 longitude:longitude
                                                                      zoom:currentZoom];
           self.mapView.camera = camera;
           [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
           }
         }
```